# When reading from a text file with readline in C# , how can I read if the position of the line I will read changes in each separate file I will read?

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist, readline

```
'''
2  @42300.693033078707200,34524409=COLOR=SECTION=DISPLAY=-32768
2  @42300.693033078707200,34524409=PATH=NAME=NAME=$PRJ$ARDAHAN2_2.KTB
2  @42300.693033067136000,34524409=SECTION=GENERAL=AMES=EKSENE MESAFE
2  @42300.693033067136000,34524409=SECTION=GENERAL=Z=KAZI KOTU
2  @42300.693033067136000,34524409=SECTION=SECDRAW=AMESBOX=0
2  @42300.693033067136000,34524409=SECTION=SECDRAW=UPDOWN=0
2  @42300.693033067136000,34524409=SECTION=SECDRAW=ZBOX=0
     1      1  26017.770 
     0      -4.9112979     410.4693101  
     0      -3.6365224     410.1894836  
     0       0.4500351     410.3161743  
     0       3.9155980     409.1699524  
     0       5.2604734     410.3972629  SAĞ
     1      2  26020.000 
     0      -4.9799434     410.4674420  SOL
     0      -4.9409100     410.0774536  
     0      -0.8472598     409.1788330  
     0       0.4261363     409.1812134  
     0       0.6297354     409.1988831  
     0       1.8846615     409.1577148  
     0       4.1917279     409.1658325  
     0       5.4726924     410.3473910  SAĞ
     1      3  26030.000 
     0      -5.0000960     410.4676211  SOL
     0      -4.8824235     409.4483337  
     0      -3.8380276     409.4503784  
     0      -0.3250690     409.3630371  
     0       0.4818728     409.3080139  
     0       1.5955057     409.2716064  
     0       4.8345747     409.2607727  SAĞ
'''
```

I have this text file with a variable number of lines:

I need to list the lines with 1 on the left in a listbox (for example: 26+017, 26+020, 26+030)

In the example I gave, data such as -4.9112979, 4693101) in the range from 26017.770 to 26020.000 belong to 26017.770.

When I click on 26+017 that I have listed in the listbox

-4.9112979 , 410.4693101
-3.6365224 , 410.1894836
I want to list data like in a separate listbox. How can I do that?

You can see the listbox example I'm trying to explain in the video below.
https://youtu.be/MiSVzC8hsQk?t=121
Notes:
a) Lines starting with 1 or 0 have 5 spaces before 1 and 0.
b) SAĞ and SOL values, I will not use them in listboxes

Answer (score 1):

Here are some pointers:

Reading a file into an array:

```
var array = File.ReadAllLines(path);
```

For each line in the array..

```
foreach(var line in array)
```

If the line starts with a 1

```
if(line.StartsWith("1"))
```

You can start a process of storing that line and all the subsequent lines (until the next 1) in a small object that holds your data

```
class Whatever {
  public string MainName { get; set; }
  public List<string> SubItems { get; set; }
}
```

For every line that starts with a 1 you can make a new one of those, store it in a list, and also in a temp variable (declared outside the loop processing the lines) so you can access it across different loop iterations. If the line doesn't start witth a 1, put the line in the sub items instead

Then you just have to show the MainName in the first listbox and when it's clicked on put the subitems in the second list. If you have a list of these Whatever you can put them in the listbox's datasource and say you want the list's DisplayMember to be "MainName"; in the SelectedXx event handler you attach to the first listbox, you can get the selected item, cast it to a Whatever and then pull the subitems for show in list2